# What does "Hot Swap error" with IntelliJ (in Java) mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotswap

I have no idea what a hot swap is and for the life of me cannot construct a google search that will find what it means in the context of my program. I was editing my class, the same way I do all the time, and when I went to run it I all of a sudden got a

> Hot Swap failed: myClassName: schema not implemented

error.

Can anyone explain this to me in Layman's terms?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You are attempting to change your source code **while the program (or IntelliJ's debugger) is still running**. This is what the HotSwap feature does according to [IntelliJ's KB.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reloading-classes.html)

Please make sure your program and/or debugger is stopped before re-launching the program and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: @user3686057 I only know from doing it so, so many times. No problem :) Glad it's working.

Comment: You are right, but the question is, what's the point of a hotswap if I have to stop and restart the debugger :)

Comment: @Storm that isn't the point of a hot swap - my answer, hence the point of the question, is for people who _accidentally_ leave the program running and try to re-run it, which triggers the hot swap feature. I assume that people who are actually trying to hot swap will know what they are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was getting worried :)